# How can I initialize a subclass by calling a super class

Tags: python, subclass, superclass

I want to be able to initialize a subclass by calling the superclass. For example, I would like to have "Animal" as a superclass and have "Dog" and "Cat" be the subclasses. Instead of calling dog=Dog("Fido", "german sheppard"), I would like to be able to call dog=Animal("Fido", "german sheppard") and yet have a dog be type Dog, not Animal

The reason behind this is that I have to control a lot of relays, circuits, etc. It seems cleaner to have one parent type in the call for human usability, yet on the code side it seems awkward to have to write the initialization to handle all the different options for types.

I have written this as a superclass and subclasses without problem. This is just a question about making it more elegant.

# this is not my code, but this seems simpler to discuss than mine is

```
class Pet(object):

def __init__(self, name, species):
    self.name = name
    self.species = species


class Dog(Pet):

def __init__(self, name, chases_cats):
    Pet.__init__(self, name, "Dog")
    self.chases_cats = chases_cats

def chasesCats(self):
    return self.chases_cats
```

Comment: If it was the other way around you could've used `super` however, the one way to do what you ask for is with child object tracking and operator overloading. In `class Pet` you will have to track all child objects created with a list for all the derived classes (read memory management and maintenance headache). Then you will have to overload the `__call__` operator to return the required child object from he corresponding list.

Comment: What are you determining type by? If you are changing the object returned, you must override `__new__` and keep a dict with `{Dog: [], Cat: []}` where the lists hold species names, for example.

Comment: When I use this class, I call it from another program that keeps track of all the different instances because I have to match instances with physical resources, i.e. Fido goes with Kennel #1, food bowl #2, etc. The only way I can think of doing it is to have the super class call a particular subclass based on type. Then in the subclass the method of calling would be overwritten with something else innocuous like "print ("this function not valid in subclass"). But, bleck. Same with having a function call the subclasses.